# Python JSON Web token (JWT) GET request 401 error with Apple Store Connect

Tags: python, python-requests, jwt

In order to generate the token for API Requests, apple outlines the [following steps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests).

The `key`, `kid`, and `iss` have all been **verified to work**. However in the following python script,

```
import jwt
import requests

# pseudo, removed secret info
# read the file, currently binary but have tried string too
with open('AuthKey_4..._.p8', 'r+b') as keyfile:
    secret = keyfile.read()

expir = round(time.time() + 20 * 60)

# sign the token with the iss, time, key, and kid with the correct alg
token = jwt.encode({'iss': '6...', 
                    'exp': f'{expir}', 
                    'aud': 'appstoreconnect-v1'},
                    secret, algorithm='ES256', 
                    headers={'alg': 'ES256', 'kid': '4...', 'typ': 'JWT'})

# decode the bytes and create the get request header
s_token = token.decode('utf-8')
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {s_token}'}

# send the get request
r = requests.get('https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports',
                 headers=headers)#, params=params)
```

`r.json()` simply returns

```
{'errors': [{'status': '401',
   'code': 'NOT_AUTHORIZED',
   'title': 'Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.',
   'detail': 'Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens'}]}
```

In addition the link in the error message appears to be broken as well.

I have tried reading in the `.p8` file in both binary and the regular string representation. I have tried passing different values in the token, removing certain values etc. I also have tried not passing the payload parameters into the GET request which also results in a 401 error. The payload information is listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports). Any help appreciated.

Comment: The link in `'detail'` got forwarded to this url for me https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

Comment: Ok thanks, the forward then just goes to the same link I provided earlier in the questions description

Comment: I think you have missed the {'some':'payload'} :- **encoded = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, key, algorithm='HS256')**

Comment: the payload is the `iss`, `exp`, and `aud`. could you be more specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

exp cannot be a string...

```
import jwt
import requests
import time

# pseudo, removed secret info
# read the file, currently binary but have tried string too
with open('AuthKey_4..._.p8', 'r+b') as keyfile:
    secret = keyfile.read()

expir = round(time.time() + 20 * 60)

# sign the token with the iss, time, key, and kid with the correct alg
token = jwt.encode({'iss': '6...', 
                    'exp': expir, 
                    'aud': 'appstoreconnect-v1'},
                    secret, algorithm='ES256', 
                    headers={'alg': 'ES256', 'kid': '4...', 'typ': 'JWT'})

# create the get request header
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}

# send the get request
r = requests.get('https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports',
                 headers=headers)#, params=params)
```